# CSS mask clipping and overlay SVG to achieve a two effect

Tags: html5, svg, css3

I am currently attempting to create a two SVG overlay / masking like the image below:

[image: See below]

I have created a SVG for the overlay. As it stands, I am trying to create two elements one for the green side and one for the blue side.

For what I am trying to achieve, is this the best approach? If not, what is?

Is it worth creating two SVGs to achieve the overlay in the example below?

```
    .hero-overlay {
       position: absolute;
        top: 0;
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
     -webkit-mask: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58412455/circle-mask.svg") no-repeat center center;
      mask: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58412455/circle-mask.svg") no-repeat center center;
      clip: rect(0px, 580px, 500px, 0px); }

    .mask-left {
      background-color: red; }

.mask-right {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
      transform: rotate(180deg);
      background-color: blue; }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/72dL79bd/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using an inline svg to create these shapes. This will provide more browser support than using the CSS mask property ([canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks)).

Both sides are created with paths and filled with the images using the pattern element :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/vm33y1wp/)**

[image: images clipped with svg]

```css
* {margin: 0;padding: 0;}
body {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-g-800-600-5.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 95vw; height: 47.5vw;
  margin: 2.5vw;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 50">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50">
      <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-c-490-500-4.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="49.5" height="50" />
      <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-c-490-500-8.jpg" x="50.5" y="0" width="49.5" height="50" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0 0 H49.5 V15 A10.02 10.02 0 0 0 49.5 35 V50 H0z" fill="url(#img)" fill-opacity="0.8" />
  <path d="M50.5 0 H100 V50 H51 V35 A10.03 10.03 0 0 0 50.5 15z" fill="url(#img)" fill-opacity="0.8" />
</svg>
```